# MariaDB always failed shutdown

Tags: mysql, mariadb, shutdown, spider

Versions :

- CentOS 7.8
- 10.4.14-MariaDB
- Using MariaDB SPIDER engine for 1 of the table

Variables :

```
log_error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
symbolic-links=0

innodb_thread_concurrency=32
innodb_buffer_pool_size=359G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=64
innodb_page_cleaners=32
innodb_purge_threads=1
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_write_io_threads=64
innodb_use_native_aio=0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_doublewrite=0
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_file_per_table=1

max_connections=10000
skip_name_resolve=1

tmp_table_size=134217728
max_heap_table_size=134217728

back_log=1000
wait_timeout=900

innodb_log_buffer_size=32M
innodb_log_file_size=768M

open_files_limit=1024000

spider_auto_increment_mode=2
spider_bgs_mode=2
spider_casual_read=1
spider_conn_recycle_mode=1
spider_multi_split_read=1
spider_same_server_link=1

max_statement_time=600
max_allowed_packet=512M
```

Whenever I attempt to shutdown MariaDB via `service mariadb stop`, it will always take about 30 minutes before it eventually failed (not stopped). As a result, I always have to first do `kill -9 <mysql pid>` before starting back the service.

In mariadb.log, I only see these :

```
2023-06-22 13:32:05 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2023-06-22 13:32:05 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2023-06-22 13:32:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
```

What I tried:

1. Tried flushing dirty data out by `set global innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 0;` `set global innodb_io_capacity = 2000;`, and observe `mysqladmin ext -i1 | grep Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty` to see if close to 0, then shutdown - doesn't help
2. Ensure no pending/existing queries in `show full processlist` then shutdown - doesn't help

Question :

1. Why is the service always failing and not able to shutdown gracefully? Weirdly, it also seems to be always 30minutes.
2. I'm suspecting it might be due to 1 table using MariaDB SPIDER engine, but I have no way to confirm this.

Comment: 10.4.14 was a very long time ago. It has had lots of fixes. Try on 10.4.30 to see if its still a problem. If its still there [install debuginfo packages](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/#installing-debug-info-packages-with-yumdnf), gdb, and [grab a stracktrace](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/#getting-backtraces-from-a-running-mysqld-process-with-gdb-on-linux) for a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org).